# Complexity classes that are closed under subtraction

Tags: complexity-theory, closure-properties, np

Are NP or P closed under subtraction? Im having a hard time deciding whether they are or aren't.
*Question was edited*

**Original question**:
Im having some hard time figuring out what languages are closed under subtraction.
Say you have 2 languages A, B ∈ NP. Is A\B ∈ NP? what about P?

**Commenters**:
My original question was extremely not accurate so i rephrased :)

Thanks!

Comment: Well, how would you decide if a word belongs to A\B?

Comment: Hint: if a language class is closed under subtraction, it contains $A \setminus A$.

Comment: Languages isn't what you're actually interested in, you want to know whether a given complexity class is closed under subtraction of languages in that class.

Comment: @G. Bach thats what i was trying to ask, are NP or P closed under subtraction? I was trying to think of an example and that is why i (mistakenly) refered to A and B.

Comment: @AndreaWilliams P is, whether NP is depends on whether NP = coNP, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A \setminus B$ is defined as $\{x | x \in A ~ and ~ not ~ x \in B \}$. If you know the complexity of checking $x \in A$ and $x \in B$, what does that tell you about the complexitty of $x \in A \setminus B$? Can you see the algorithm for checking it?

Comment: Yes, thanks! As @G. Bach suggested, i have concluded that P is closed under subtraction whereas NP isn't.

Comment: @AndreaWilliams Just to be clear, I don't know whether NP is closed under subtraction.