# What is wrong with this argument that if A is NP Complete, but B is in P, then A\B is NP Complete and B\A is NP Complete as well?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, np-complete, polynomial-time, p-vs-np

The following seems to me to be relevant to [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18897/complexity-classes-that-are-closed-under-subtraction/112022?noredirect=1#comment239251_112022), but to me is an interesting exercise, especially since I have not formally worked with complexity before, but I want to learn more:

Suppose that A is NP-Complete, but B is in P. I claim that A\B is NP-Complete and B\A is NP-Complete as well. To see this, assume first that A\B is in P, and let X and Y be polynomial-time algorithms for B and for A\B, respectively. "Concatenating" X and Y as follows yields an algorithm Z for A:

Given L, test L using X;
if X outputs "yes", test using Y;
if Y yields "yes", output "no" and stop;
if X yields "no", output "no" and stop; output "yes" otherwise and stop.

This algorithm Z runs in polynomial time, because if the (polynomial time) complexity exponent of X is k and the (polynomial time) complexity exponent of Y is n, then this algorithm clearly has (polynomial time) complexity exponent m=max(k,n). This would provide proof that P=NP, so A\B is NP-Complete.

Now suppose that B\A is in P. This time, let Y' be a polynomial-time algorithm for B\A and let X be as above. We construct an algorithm Z' for A, as follows:

Given L, test L using X;
if X outputs "yes", test using Y';
if Y yields "no", output "yes" and stop;
if X yields "no", test using Y'; if Y yields "no", output "yes" and stop;
output "no" otherwise and stop.

This yields a polynomial-time algorithm for A, and so again, this would entail that P=NP, so B\A also is NP-Complete.

+++++++++End of Example++++++++++++

While I don't see anything wrong with the above at the moment, perhaps I have a mistake or complexity miscalculation? ...because for a while, as I was writing the second algorithm, I began to think it was odd and perhaps impossible that I can be right about B\A also being NP-Complete...

As I said, I'm somewhat new to this area, so feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C$ be any language in $NP \setminus \{ \emptyset \}$. Notice that such a $C$ exists (e.g., $C = \Sigma^*$).

The claim "if $A$ is $NP$-Complete and $B$ is in $P$ then $A \setminus B$ is $NP$-complete" is false (regardless of whether $P=NP$).
To see this pick $B=\Sigma^*$. Then $A \setminus B = \emptyset$.
Since there is no polynomial-time reduction from $C$ to $A \setminus B $, we know that $A \setminus B$ cannot be $NP$-hard and hence cannot be $NP$-complete.

Substituting $B=\Sigma^*$ in your argument, you obtain an algorithm $Z$ that accepts $\Sigma^*$, but $\Sigma^* \neq A$ (since $A$ is $NP$-complete). This shows that your claim that $Z$ is an algorithm for $A$ is wrong.

The claim "if $A$ is $NP$-Complete and $B$ is in $P$ then $B \setminus A$ is $NP$-complete" is also false (regardless of whether $P=NP$). To see this simply pick $B = \emptyset$. Since there is no polynomial-time reduction from $C$ to $B \setminus A$ we know that $B \setminus A$ cannot be $NP$-hard and hence cannot be $NP$-complete.

Substituting $B=\emptyset$ in your argument, you obtain an algorithm $Z'$ that accepts $\Sigma^*$, hence $Z'$ is not an algorithm for $A \neq \Sigma^*$.

Another logical error that you have in your proof is assuming that the complement of "$A \setminus B$ (resp. $B \setminus A$) is in $P$" is "$A \setminus B$ (resp. $B \setminus A$) is $NP$-complete". If $P \neq NP$ then there are problems in $NP \setminus P$ that are not $NP$-complete. See Ladner's theorem and the class [$NP$-Intermediate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-intermediate).

Comment: Your answer does not address the question.  The question was "What is wrong with this argument...", not "Is it true that if  is -Complete and  is in  then ∖ is -complete?".

Comment: The answer provides a counterxample. Once you substitute $B = \Sigma^*$  and $B=\emptyset$ in the proposed proofs it's obvious where they break down.

Comment: That's not at all obvious for people who don't already know your notation.

Comment: I'm using standard notation.

Comment: Did you read this part:  "The following seems to me to be relevant to this question, but to me is an interesting exercise, especially since I have not formally worked with complexity before, but I want to learn more"?  Apparently not.  Where did you cite a reference for this "standard notation"?  I don't see it in your comments.

Comment: Michael Sipser. "Introduction to the theory of computation" 3rd edition. pp. 1-441. Cengage Learning. 2013. ISBN: 978-1-133-18779-0.
$$\text{and}$$
Sanjeev Arora, Boaz Barak. "Computational complexity - A Modern Approach". pp. 1-543. Cambridge University Press, 2009. ISBN: 978-0-521-42426-4.

Answer (score 1):

Take $B=\Sigma^*$. Obviously, $A\setminus B=\emptyset$ is not NP-complete. I'm not sure how concatenation has anything to do with set subtraction, but obviously, concatenating $B=\Sigma^*$ to $A\setminus B=\emptyset$ won't yield $A$ back, since $\Sigma^* \emptyset=\emptyset$ as $\emptyset$ doesn't contain any words.

Comment: My argument does not concatenate sets, and I don't know what you mean by the word "substruction" at all.  Also, I don't know what you mean by  "Σ∗".

Comment: $\Sigma^*$ is the set of all possible words. If you don't know what set subtraction is, maybe you want to consider learning a bit of set theory before. Just the basic stuff: union, intersection, subtraction, etc. will be enough. About the concatenation, what exactly did you mean by that? What *do* you concatenate?

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm $Z$ doesn't decide $A$. If the input is in both $A$ and $B$, then it returns "no" even though the correct answer is "yes." The error can't be fixed, since it's generally impossible to deduce whether an input is in $A$ if you only know its membership status in $B$ and $A \setminus B$.